# Blogger : how to connect two subdomain with two deferent blog on same blogger account

Tags: blogger, cname

I have two subdomain in my hosting ,I created two blog in my blogger
I tried first one with CNAME ar and target ghs.google.com with secure CNAME ,it is connected correctly and work fine.
I tried for second one ,it didn't asked me for CNAME record ,I used ku CNAME with ghs.google.com and same secure CNAME record but didn't work.

How can do it?

[first blog](http://ar.hlo-iq.org/)

[second blog](http://ku.hlo-iq.org/)